# Removing duplicates with a condition in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with text as one column and its labels as other column.
The texts are duplicates with a single label.
I want to remove these duplicates and keep the records for only the label specified.

Sample dataframe:

```
                 text label
0          great view     a
1          great view     b
2        good balcony     a
3        nice service     a
4        nice service     b
5        nice service     c
6           bad rooms     f
7     nice restaurant     a
8     nice restaurant     d
9   nice beach nearby     x
10        good casino     z
```

Now if I want to keep the text wherever label a is present and remove only the duplicates.
Sample output:

```
          text label
0         great view     a
1       good balcony     a
2       nice service     a
3          bad rooms     f
4    nice restaurant     a
5  nice beach nearby     x
6        good casino     z
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple try `sort_values` before `drop_duplicates`, since the df will first ordered by the `label` by the order of alpha beta (a>b yield to True)

```
df=df.sort_values('label').drop_duplicates('text')
```

Or

```
df=df.sort_values('label').groupby('text').head(1)
```

Update

```
Valuetokeep='a'

df=df.iloc[(df.label!=Valuetokeep).argsort()].drop_duplicates('text')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That will help only when I want to keep label 'a' as my selected label. But if I select label 'b' and want to drop duplicates associated with label 'a' then it doesn't work.